# I would go a AngularJS array with PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I have these data:

controller.js (angularJS)

```
datas = {
    'variable' : $scope.variables,
};

$http.post('http://localhost/proyectos/3.0copy/app/partials/createJson.php', datas).then(function() {
    console.log(datas);
});
```

[image: Array Log Google Chrome]

I use a http who send me these variables to create Json.php where the array and try to print me everything. What I have is this:

createJson.php

```
<?php    
    $datos = $request->datas;
    echo $datos;

    $myData = json_decode($_POST['datas']);

    print_r($myData);

      if(file_get_contents("php://input")){
        $json = file_get_contents("php://input");

      $file = fopen($dir,'w+');
      fwrite($file, $email);
      fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

I do not return anything, I generated the file but empty.

Comment: `$input = file_get_contents("php://input");if (!empty($input)) { ... fwrite($file,$input); ... }` read input stream once only

Comment: But to go that array AngularJS in PHP as I can do? @cske

Comment: file was empty becouse of `php://input` coud only be read once [see](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: I want to write an array of AngularJS you see in the browser to a TXT ... @cske

Comment: I understand your goal, i'm tring to explain why and where your php code fails, although `fwrite($file, $email);` shoud be `fwrite($file, $json);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

  $dir='../less/variables.json';

if(file_exists($dir)) 
{ 
if(unlink($dir)) 
print "El archivo fue borrado"; 
} 
else 
print "Este archivo no existe"; 

$datos = $request->datas;
echo $datos;

$myData = json_decode($_POST['datas']);

print_r($myData);

  if(file_get_contents("php://input")){
    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");

  $file = fopen($dir,'w+');
  fwrite($file, $json);
  fclose($file);
}

?>
```